# Missing $ inserted 5

Tags: errors

I'm kind of new to latex and I keep having the error: 'missing $ inserted' in the following piece of code:

```
\sigma$_1$  and \sigma$_3$ horizontal
```

anyone knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `\sigma` is a math command so `$\sigma_{1}$` and in general surround the _entire_ expression with `$` not just subterms.